# CKeditor 4 - Click radiobuttons and add check=cheked automatically inside editor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor4.x

In CKEditor 4, a custom plugin has been created.

When the user loads the editor, a template is loaded and put in the editor, and the content is then run through a widget which makes the appropriate elements in the template editable with editable objects.

One part of the template is a list of radio buttons that the user has to check out. Clicking on them does nothing. Is there a way to make the `ul>li` list with radio buttons clickable, so that the underlying html is modified to include the `checked="checked"` attribute?